# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method, en android cuando se gira el dispositivo

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, nullpointerexception

Buen día comunidad. Estoy desarrollando una app para android que consiste en visualizar articulos de noticias en la pantalla, parecido a Flipboard. Tengo una activity llamada MenuArticuloActivity que contiene un MenuArticuloFragment que a su vez muestra CardViews en un RecyclerView que contienen la imagen y el titulo del articulo. Cuando el usuario selecciona una CardView la app cambia a la activity ArticuloActivity, donde se renderiza el articulo seleccionado. En ese Intent que cambia de activity, la MenuArticuloActivity envia un Bundle a la ArticuloActivity que contiene un objeto POJO llamado Articulo cuyos atributos son un titulo, una imagen y un contenido. Hasta aquí todo funciona bien, el problema es que cuando giro la pantalla de vertical (Portrait) a horizontal (landscape), o viceversa, la app crashea y aparece el error del NullPointerException.

Este es mi objeto Articulo:

public class Articulo extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

```
@PrimaryKey
private Integer id;
private int imagen;
@Required
private String titulo;
private int contenido;
private int id_carp;

public Articulo(){

}

public Articulo(int imagen, String titulo, int contenido) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.contenido = contenido;
}

public Articulo(int imagen, String titulo, int contenido, int id_carp) {
    this.id = MyApplication.ArticuloID.incrementAndGet();
    this.imagen = imagen;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.contenido = contenido;
    this.id_carp = id_carp;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(int imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public int getContenido() {
    return contenido;
}

public void setContenido(int contenido) {
    this.contenido = contenido;
}

public int getId_carp() {
    return id_carp;
}

public void setId_carp(int id_carp) {
    this.id_carp = id_carp;
}
```

}

esta es la MenuArticulosFragment. Seccion es otro objeto POJO que contiene ArrayList de objetos Articulo.

public class MenuArticulosFragment extends Fragment {

```
private ArrayList<Seccion> secciones;
private Seccion seccion;

private int position;

private List<Articulo> articulos;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public MenuArticulosFragment() {

}

public MenuArticulosFragment(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    secciones = MyGenerador.getSecciones();
    seccion = secciones.get(position);

    articulos = seccion.getArticulos();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_articulos, container, false);


    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenuArticulo);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    adapter = new ArticuloAdapter(articulos, R.layout.articulo_item, new ArticuloAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Articulo articulo, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ArticuloActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            bundle1.putSerializable("articulo", articulos.get(position));
            intent.putExtras(bundle1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

y esta es la ArticuloActivity

public class ArticuloActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RealmChangeListener<RealmResults> {

```
private Articulo articulo;

private ImageButton btn_favorites;
private ImageButton btn_atras;

private String title;
private int article;
private int imagen;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private Realm realm;
private RealmResults<Carpeta> carpetas;

private boolean isTablet;
private Fragment fragment;
private Fragment fragmentTab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_articulo);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    carpetas = realm.where(Carpeta.class).findAll();
    carpetas.addChangeListener(this);

    btn_favorites = findViewById(R.id.btn_favorites);
    btn_atras = findViewById(R.id.btn_atras);

    btn_favorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showAlertForRegisterNewArticulo();
        }
    });

    btn_atras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    articulo = (Articulo) bundle.getSerializable("articulo");

    title = articulo.getTitulo();
    article = articulo.getContenido();
    imagen = articulo.getImagen();

    isTablet = (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentIsTabletArticulo) != null);

    if(isTablet){
        fragmentTab = new ArticuloFragmentTablet(articulo);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame_articulo_tablet, fragmentTab).commit();
    } else {
        fragment = new ArticuloFragment(articulo);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame_articulo, fragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Finalmente este es el ArticuloFragment que renderiza en la pantalla el objeto Articulo

public class ArticuloFragmentTablet extends Fragment {

```
private Articulo articulo;

private ImageView image;
private TextView titulo;
private TextView contenido;

private String title;
private int article;
private int imagen;

public ArticuloFragmentTablet() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public ArticuloFragmentTablet(Articulo articulo) {
    this.articulo = articulo;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    title = articulo.getTitulo();
    article = articulo.getContenido();
    imagen = articulo.getImagen();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulo_tablet, container, false);

    image = view.findViewById(R.id.imageArticulo);
    titulo = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewArticuloTitulo);
    contenido = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewArticuloContenido);

    Picasso.get().load(imagen).fit().into(image);
    titulo.setText(title);
    contenido.setText(article);

    return view;
}
```

}

El ArticuloFragmentTablet es exactamente igual que el ArticuloFragment, solo que con diferente layout.

Muchas gracias de antemano comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que creo que está pasando es que tras rotar la pantalla, la aplicación se destruye y se vuelve a crear. Como se vuelve a iniciar, los argumentos que le pasaste a través por el intent se pierden. Al perderse y querer recuperarlos de nuevo, te arroja ese error, es decir, el NullPointerException.

Hay dos maneras de solucionar esto: deshabilitas la rotación del teléfono desde el archivo Manifest a cada una de tus actividades o aplicas una sub clase que extienda de ViewModel para que se encargue de almacenar la información tras los cambios de configuración de tu aplicación, como lo es en este caso, la rotación del teléfono.

Te anexo estos links como referencia a lo que explico:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=es
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

PD: No consideraría esto como una respuesta, más bien como un comentario a tu pregunta para ayudarte, pero no me deja hacerlo porque me hace falta reputación :/ jaja

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que pasa, al rotar la pantalla y destruirse la Activity el objeto Artículo que envíe como argumento se pierde. Lo que imagine que podría hacer es volver a enviar el objeto Artículo en el método onDestroy pero no sé si algo así sería posible. Gracias por el aporte, estudiaré la documentación que me dejaste